# When I move my express code from route file to controller file the api does not work.Hitting the api from the postman results in a non-ending request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I had written the post and get function in authorRouter.js file the api's were working, but when I moved those functions to authorController.js file in the controllers folder the api's stopped working. When I call the api from postman it results in a never ending request. I was earlier calling the controller function from router file this way:

```
.post(controller.post)
.get(controller.get)
```

but it was giving me an error "Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]" so I edited my router file as below:

authorRouter.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const authorController = require('../controllers/authorController');

function routes(Author){
    const authorRouter = express.Router();
    const controller = authorController(Author);
    authorRouter.route('/author')
    .post( function(req, res){
        controller.post
      })
      .get( function(req,res){
           controller.get
       }     
       );
// .post((req,res)=>{
//     const author = new Author(req.body);

//     author.save();
//     return res.status(201).json(author);
// })
// .get((req,res)=>{
//     const query = {};
//     if(req.query.name){
//         query.name = req.query.name;
//     }
//      Author.find(query,(err,authors)=>{
//      if(err){
//          return res.send(err);
//      }
//         return res.json(authors);  
//     });
//  });

authorRouter.use('/author/:authorId',(req,res,next)=>{
    Author.findById(req.params.authorId,(err,author)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.send(err);
        }
        if(author){
            req.author =author;
            return next();
        }
           return res.sendStatus(404);  
       });
});
authorRouter.route('/author/:authorId')
.get((req,res)=>{
    res.json(req.author);
 })
 .put((req,res)=>{
         const {author}  =req;
         author.name = req.body.name;
         author.book = req.body.book;
         author.age = req.body.age;
         req.author.save((err)=>{
            if(err){
                return res.send(err);
            }
            return res.json(author);
        })

 })
 .patch((req,res)=>{
     const { author} =req;
     if (req.body._id){
         delete req.body._id;
     }
     Object.entries(req.body).forEach(item=>{
         const key = item[0];
         const value = item[1];
         author[key]= value;
     });
     req.author.save((err)=>{
         if(err){
             return res.send(err);
         }
         return res.json(author);
     });
 })
 .delete((req,res)=>{
     req.authorId.remove((err)=>{
         if(err){
            return res.send(err);
         }
         return res.sendStatus(204);
     })

 });

 return authorRouter;

}


module.exports= routes;
```

authorController.js file

```
 function authorController(Author){
    function post(req,res){
      const author = new Author(req.body);
      author.save();
      return res.status(201).json(author);
    }

    function get(req,res) {
      const query = {};
      if(req.query.name){
        query.name = req.query.name;
      }
      Author.find(query,(err,authors)=>{
       if(err){
         return res.send(err);
        }
        return res.json(authors);  
      });   
    }
        return(post, get );
  }

  module.exports = authorController;
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
.post(function (req, res) {
  controller.post(req, res);
})
```

Or

```
.post(controller.post);
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code in the authorRouter.js back to how I was earlier calling the function in the controller

```
.post(controller.post)
.get(controller.get);
```

and in the  the controller file I replaced

```
 return(post, get );
```

with

```
return {post,get};
```

Now the code is working.The error was that I was not using curly braces.